# Convert set to a hashable type

Tags: python, oop, hash, set

I have some variables that are related two by two, and I wish to stock them as attributes of `Siblings` objects.

So, I create a class:

```
def Siblings(object):
    def __init__(self, brother, sister):
        self._brother = brother
        self._sister = sister

    def __eq__(self, other):
        if isinstance(other, Siblings):
            return {self._brother, self._sister} == {other._brother, other._sister}

    def __hash__(self):
        return hash((self._brother, self._sister)
```

The reason why I am using sets in `__eq__` is that I do not know (and do not care) which variable will be considered as brother and which as sister.
In fact,

```
s1 = Siblings(1,2)
s2 = Siblings(2,1)
print(s1 == s2)
```

prints True, which is what I need.

The problem is that my `Siblings` objects need to be used as dictionary keys, so that `s1` and `s2` mentioned above correspond to the same key.

However:

```
a = {s1: 5}
a[s2] = 4
```

does not modify the value 5, as I want, but instead it adds a new key-value pair. This is understandable by the way my `__hash__` is defined.

I tried replacing the vector by a set in `__hash__`, but I get

> TypeError: unhashable type: 'set'

Any suggestions on how to solve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hash with a `frozenset` instead of a tuple:

```
def __hash__(self):
    return hash(frozenset([self._brother, self._sister]))
```

Unrelated to the question, but recommended - you should avoid returning `None` in the `__eq__`:

```
def __eq__(self, other):
    if isinstance(other, Siblings):
        return {self._brother, self._sister} == {other._brother, other._sister}
    return NotImplemented
```

Note that the hash must not change within an object's timeline. As long as you don't write to the `_brother` and `_sister` attributes after init, you should be safe.

Answer (score 3):

Python has a hashable set called [`frozenset`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#frozenset) built-in. It is immutable, so if you do need to change it you have to create a new object (just like with tuples).

```
a = frozenset([1, 2])
b = frozenset([2, 1])
a == b
# True

d = {a: "a"}
# {frozenset({1, 2}): 'a'}
d[b] = "b"
# {frozenset({1, 2}): 'b'}

a.add(3) 
# AttributeError: 'frozenset' object has no attribute 'add'

a = a | {3}
# frozenset({1, 2, 3})
```

Answer (score 1):

As other answers have already pointed out, using [frozenset](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#frozenset) is a valid approach, another also useful choice for these type of cases is considering using [namedtuples](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.namedtuple), example below:

```
from collections import namedtuple

BaseSiblings = namedtuple('Siblings', 'brother sister')


class Siblings(BaseSiblings):

    def __hash__(self):
        return super().__hash__()

    def __eq__(self, other):
        if isinstance(other, Siblings):
            return {self.brother, self.sister} == {other.brother, other.sister}

        return NotImplemented

obj1 = Siblings('a', 'b')
print(obj1)
obj2 = Siblings('b', 'a')
print(obj2 == obj1)
print({obj1: '1'} == {obj2: '1'})
```

Comment: O.P. wants order-insensitive compare, though.