# Hash function for sets of IDs

Tags: python, algorithm, hash, set

Is there a hash algorithm/function in Python that is able to convert sets of unique strings to a single hash string?

For example, a set of `{a,b,c}` would return some unique ID, the same unique ID as for `{c,a,b}` or `{b,c,a}` etc.

Comment: sort first, then hash

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Convert set to a hashable type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55731439/convert-set-to-a-hashable-type)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is the builtin [hash](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#hash) function for this purpose. Two [frozensets](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#frozenset) containing the same values are guaranteed to have the same hash.

```py
>>> s=frozenset(('hello','abc','12','42','zyx'))
>>> t=frozenset(('zyx','hello','abc','42','12'))
>>> s
frozenset({'abc', '42', '12', 'hello', 'zyx'})
>>> t
frozenset({'abc', '42', 'hello', '12', 'zyx'})
>>> hash(s)
8290365720384972439
>>> hash(t)
8290365720384972439
>>> hash(s)==hash(t)
True
```